# Web scraping with PHP and HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the site inside the code but I would it in table format.

```
$url='http://www.arbworld.net/en/moneyway';
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
    libxml_clear_errors();


    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col=$xp->query('//table[@class="grid"]/tr[@class="belowHeader"]/td');

    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->textContent;
    }
```

Now the output is this:

> Romanian Liga I22.Dec 18:00:00 FCSBUniversitat2.063.33.999.9 %€ 2070.1
>   %€ 00 %€ 0€ 207 22.Dec 18:00:00 Italian Serie A22.Dec 11:30:00
>   AtalantaAC Milan1.8844.499.7 %€ 21 5580.1 %€ 170.2 %€ 46€ 21 622
>   22.Dec 11:30:00 English League 221.Dec 15:0
>   0:00

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the rows instead of the columns (without the `/td` at the end), then simply put everything into an HTML table, with one `<tr>` for each row:

```
<?php
// your current code

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows = $xp->query('//table[@class="grid"]/tr[@class="belowHeader"]');
?>

<table>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($row->childNodes as $col): ?>
      <?php if ($col->getAttribute('style') !== 'display:none'): ?>
        <?php foreach ($col->childNodes as $colPart): ?>
          <?php if ($colText = trim($colPart->textContent)): ?>
          <td><?= $colText ?></td>
          <?php elseif ($colPart instanceof DOMElement && $colPart->tagName === 'a'): ?>
            <?php
            $href = $colPart->getAttribute('href');
            if (strpos($href, 'javascript') !== 0):
            ?>
            <td><?= $colPart->getAttribute('href') ?></td>
            <?php endif ?>
          <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! The last thing. How can I separate this: "80.9 %€ 245 063" and insert in two differents columns?

Comment: @FilippoSchiera Check my last edit. Splitting the original columns into their children nodes should do the trick.

Comment: Great for second time. The last last last thing. In last table of website, there is a column that contains an image inside href --> **<a href="https://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?pid=66957&amp;bid=9017&amp;redirecturl=https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/marketactivity?id=1.167634743&amp;selectionId=56323" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="https://arbworld.net/flags/chart.png" alt="odds stats"></a>**

Comment: I would to scrape the redirecturl=***https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/marketactivity?id=1.167634743&amp;selectionId=56323***

After that we can also close the discussion. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: @FilippoSchiera I made another edit. This is getting a little bit too specific now though. I'll let you handle the rest.

Comment: I took a look at the domxpath syntax. should I use lastchild to scrape the last column?

Comment: @FilippoSchiera Sorry I forgot to edit my answer when I posted my previous comment. Check it out now.

Comment: In the first column there are "javascript:void(0)" , the link repeat two times and there are 2 columns that contains same text of the columns Date in arbworld

Comment: Edited again, should be better. The two links are actually different (for the two different buttons at the end of each line). This will be my last edit, hopefully that's enough.